# Python 3: Groupby 3 DataFrame columns to check availability in a 4th column and add label 0 or 1 to 5th column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My first time posting on StackoOverflow. Please be kind.

I tried to find the exact solution for this problem but have failed to do so.

What I am attempting to do is groupby ***ProductID, Class, Material*** columns to see what are the null and non-null values in a column and assign 0 and 1 respectively in the column ***Level***.

My Dataframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRZcY.jpg

My Target Dataframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWi5y.jpg

I am unable to get a label of 0's and 1's for the missing values in ***Material*** column. Please help!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you include the dataframes as code-formatted text instead of images (you can use the [edit] feature)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['level'] = df[['ProductID', 'Class', 'Material']]\
                .apply(lambda x: 0 if x.isna().sum() > 0 else 1, axis=1)
```

Comment: This helped a lot. I am unable to vote due to low reputation points, but if someone else could upvote this answer, would be great. Thanks much! :)

Comment: But you can still mark this answer as the valid answer to your question. There is a tick mark just around the upvote sumbol of my answer.